# Does true iPhone/iPad simulator exist?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

I'm looking for true iPhone and iPad simulators for web development. Obviously websites like:

- http://alexw.me/ipad2/
- http://iphone4simulator.com/
- http://ipadpeek.com/
- Adobe AIR version of iPad

won't do the trick because they don't even support `meta="viewport"`, they don't send proper user agent to website, they don't support touch events and their code parser is different from true iPhone/iPad parser.

Bugs that appear on iPad/iPhone are never observed on standard browsers and the only browser that partially has the same issues is IE7. That's why I'd like to test.

**Are they any TRUE iPhone/iPad/Android simulators?**

Comment: there is no simulator for android..it has emulator..

Comment: what is android doing in this question?

Comment: Nevermind Android :) I just added it because it's as common as iPhone and I couldn't find true simulator either. iPhone/iPad simulators are the most important for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; it comes with the Xcode IDE (Mac only).

I guess this is probably not what you wanted to hear, but it's the truth.

The best option, IMHO, would be to get a cheap-ish used iPad (and iPod Touch). You can't get a good feeling for the touch interaction from a simulator.

Comment: Xcode for Mac is acceptable solution for me :) Better than buying those iDevices. They are at least 50% more expensive in my country ($1000+ for iPad3, $900+ for iPhone 4S).

I will let you know if it works like expected.